# how to check if a sentry alert was sent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, request, guzzle

I have an app that sends alerts in case there is something wrong,

app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
...
public function register()
{
   $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
          if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
              app('sentry')->captureException($e);
          }
    }
}
...
```

and also I added a custom middleware:

ErrorInExternalProvider.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response): void
    {
        $status = $response->status();
        if ($status === 500) {
            report(new \Error($response->getContent(), $status));
        }
    }
```

When there is a problem while doing some external requests using Saloon/Guzzle, it also needs to send an alert, it is working.

But in the case there is a problem with my app, not the provider, it triggers the alert twice, one alert because something bad happened and one other alert because it is entering to the condition `$status === 500`.

Is it required for the external request? What can I do, maybe my logic is wrong, I have written custom classes for all the external requests, do I need to modify all of them?

EDIT:
if I remove this part:

report(new \Error($response->getContent(), $status));

Then when there is a 500 status code error in the response of the external provider, it does not sent any alert